# Make folders created in aws3 bucket public or private in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, directory, public, bucket

I have created aws3 bucket and successfully uploaded files into it. I would like to make two folders in the bucket(one folder for storing public files and the other for storing private files).How can I set the folder access private or public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying from AWS console. In such case, just right click your folder which you want to make as public. On right click, there should be one option as "make-public", that should make it public.

*Programmatically with Java:*
In case, to make folder (it's key in technical term of S3) you need to use "Canned ACL.

Hence, you code should look like as follows:
**s3client.putObject(...).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)**

see ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl

As you mentioned in comment, everyone should have read access to public folder, in such case have one bucket level policy that grants "public" named folder access to everyone.

Example of policy:
Example:

```
    {
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
            "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::test-b11/public/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

where bucket name is "test-b11" and that has public folder as "public"

From console, click a bucket, go to tab of "permissions" and click "Bucket policy" where you need to upload policy.

Comment: even if i am making the folder as "public" ,I am not able to access the files uploaded in the folder publicly. I should make indiviual files in that folder public.so what should i do?

Comment: please refer, edited answer that solves your problem by applying "bucket policy"

Comment: thnq Tejas.Can you please send the code to make a folder files private.

Comment: By default, objects are private. i.e. expect in a public folder defined by bucket policy, rest of stuffs remain as private. Java code                                                                     private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, File file) {
    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file);
// comment it            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
}